# c++ Function to return an enum?

Tags: c++, function, enums

So I have this namespace called paddleNS for the class called paddle, inside paddleNS I have an enum known as colour

```
namespace paddleNS
{
   enum COLOUR {WHITE = 0, RED = 1, PURPLE = 2, BLUE = 3, GREEN = 4, YELLOW = 5, ORANGE = 6};
}

class Paddle : public Entity
{
private:
    paddleNS::COLOUR colour;
public:
    void NextColour();
    void PreviousColour();
    void PaddleColour(paddleNS::COLOUR col) { colour = col; }
};
```

Now then, what I was wondering is how would I go about creating a function that will return what the colour currently is also is there an easier way to return it in text form instead of a value or am I better of just using a switch to figure out what the colour is?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just return the enum by value:

```
class Paddle : public Entity
{
  // as before...

  paddleNS::COLOUR currentColour() const { return colour; }
};
```

Comment: Is there an easier way to return it in text form though or am I better of just using a switch to figure out what the colour is? - This was the bit I was missing out, Thats my bad..

Comment: @Andy you want a string representation of your enum?

Comment: @Andy I thought that might be the issue. A switch, or `std::map<paddleNS::COLOUR, std::string>`. Try to ask questions a bit more precisely. juanchopanza answered the question you actually asked.

Comment: @Andy The fact that you want the string form should really be the most prominent part of your question!

Comment: @Andy no easy way to do it, a switch/map is easiest. Or leave enums and create/reuse some template `Enumeration<>` class that has `to_string()` method

Comment: @Andy then you need to provide some kind of mapping between enum values and strings. Unfortunately there is no easy, universally accepted way to do that, but there are plenty of SO questions on that topic.

Comment: What about as an array of chars? Is that a possibility?

Comment: @Andy there are many possibilities, but you need to provide a mapping. Bear in mind that enums don't have to start with `0`, and you can have gaps between their values, so they cannot be universally used for indexing (otherwise the solution would be trivial).

Answer (score 4):

Hey you can make your function in header that look like this:

```
enum COLOUR function();
```

and when you define a function:

```
enum Paddle::COLOUR Paddle::function(){
        // return some variable that hold enum of COLOUR
}
```

in main.cpp i `enter code here`think you can manage it

Answer (score 2):

```
class Paddle : public Entity
{
  // ----

  const char* currentColour() const { 
switch(couleur)
{
 case WHITE:
   return "white";
   break;
//And so on
}
}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep an array of strings where the indix in to this array of strings matches the enum value you are using.

So if you have:

```
enum COLOUR {WHITE = 0, RED = 1, PURPLE = 2, BLUE = 3, GREEN = 4, YELLOW = 5, ORANGE = 6};
```

I would then have an array defined:

```
String colors[] = {white, red, purple, blue, green, yellow, orange}
```

Then when you have a function return an enum of this type you can just put it into your array and get the correct color in string format.